# Difference between convex set, closed convex set, polyhedron and polytope?

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

I'm having a hard time differentiating between a  convex set, a closed convex set, a polyhedron and a polytope? I have a good understanding of what a convex set is, but I can't seem to understand was further conditions are placed if it is 'closed'.
Similarly, I know a polyhedron is the intersection of half-spaces(which are convex sets) so its a convex set too. But is it a closed convex set or not?
And what is meant by 'bounded', when we say that a polytope is a bounded polyhedron?

I'd really appreciate a reply, thank you!

Comment: Please include your current understanding/definitions of each of the four you mention in your first sentences.  What do your notes and/or textbook say (regarding closed convex sets.  Then, if there are points you have access to that you don't understand, you can ask for clarity.  Else this question is too broad, and/or, without context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convex set is closed if the limit of any convergent sequence of points from the set is contained in the set. As a simple example in one dimension, $[a,b]$ is a closed convex set but $(a,b)$ is not. The latter is convex, but you can easily find a sequence of points in the interval converging to $a$, and $a$ does not belong to the set.

A polyhedron is a set (not necessarily closed, not necessarily bounded and not necessarily convex) with a finite number of flat sides. As the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron) notes, there is a lack of uniformity in how people interpret the word "polyhedron". The "toroidal polyhedron" diagram in that entry depicts a polyhedron that is clearly not convex (and is not an intersection of half-spaces).

A *convex* polyhedron is the intersection of a finite number of half-spaces, where a half-space is basically one side of a hyperplane. So, for instance, $X=\lbrace x\in \Re^2 : x_1 \ge 0, x_2 \ge 0, x_1 - x_2 \ge -1\rbrace$ is a convex polyhedron, and is closed.

Consider $Y=\lbrace x\in \Re^2 : x_1 \ge 0, x_2 \ge 0, x_1 - x_2 > -1\rbrace$ (where the last inequality is weak). It is again the intersection of half-spaces, including two of the three bounding hyperplanes but not the third one, so it is a convex polyhedron but not closed. $(0,1)$ belongs to $X$ but not $Y$, but you can find a sequence of points in $Y$ converging to it.

"Bounded" just means extending finitely far in any direction. A polytope is a closed, bounded polyhedron, and a convex polytope is a closed, bounded, convex polyhedron. The polyhedron $X$ above is not bounded (because $(M, M)$ is in the set for arbitrarily large $M$). If we intersect $X$ with the half-space $x_1 \le 10$, we get a closed, bounded, convex polyhedron, hence a polytope. In an optimization context, being closed and bounded guarantees that the maximum or minimum of a continuous objective function over the set is achieved somewhere in the set. If the set is either not closed or not bounded, it may be that the objective function $f(x)$ has no minimum (or maximum, whichever matters), but instead there is a lower (upper) bound that is approached but never reached by a sequence of points in the set.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.

Comment: @prubin How about non-negative constraints, are they closed convex sets? It would be great if you can explain what you meant by "A convex set is closed if the limit of any sequence of points from the set is contained in the set" using an example. What we consider as "sequence of points"?

Comment: A sequence of points is an infinite collection of points from the set, put in a specific order. I added the word "convergent" above, because we are only concerned with sequences that have a limit. If $x_1,x_2,...$ all belong to the set and $x=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n$ exists, for the set to be closed $x$ must be in the set.

Comment: Non-negativity constraints are not sets, they are constraints, but a set characterized by a number of non-negativity constraints and nothing else will be closed. For a set characterized by a mix of non-negativity and other constraints, whether it is closed will depend on the other constraints -- the non-negativity constraints will neither force it to be closed nor prevent it from being closed.